# Cast n level nested models to corresponding classes in Ruby

Tags: ruby, json, parsing, casting

I'm new to ruby. I'm calling a `REST` api from ruby client, and that API returns a model. Model contains nested complex objects, upto 4 level on average. Lets say, the Model is `Customer` and I have created a class `Customer` in my ruby client app. Imagine the following:

outer class:

```
class Customer
 def CustomerCards=(address) #inner complex object
  @address = address
 end
 #... other complex objects

end
```

inner class `CustomerCard`

```
class CustomerCard
 def CardDetails=(carddetails) #inner-inner complex object
  @carddetails= carddetails
 end
 #... other complex objects

end
```

inner->inner class `CardDetails`

```
class CardDetails
 def Cardvalidations=(cardvalidations) #inner-inner-inner complex object
  @cardvalidations = cardvalidations
 end
 #... other complex objects

end
```

inner->inner->inner class `CardValidations`

```
class Cardvalidations
 def MaxTranxLimit=(maxTranxLimit ) #inner-inner-inner complex object
  @maxTranxLimit= maxTranxLimit
 end
 #... other complex objects

end
```

In this case, I have to manually `JSON.parse` each property *(which returns hash)*, and cast it to corresponding object, upto n-level. Which doesn't seem an efficient solution. *(Imagine, I have around 8 complex properties in `Customer` model, and further each property's model contains another 8 complex properties)*

**Question:** Is there any generic way to do this?

I understand, we cannot define type of property in ruby class, but as I'm new to Ruby, and I must be missing something. and there must be some solution to this, as REST calls are very common.

Comment: May we see an example of hash coming? I believe one might call objects the same way as they are called in the hash and instantiate them with metaprogramming technique (basically it’s called “reflection” in Java-like languages.)

Comment: @mudasobwa, exactly, you sound like what I'm looking for. Here is the hash I get:

`{"AddressId"=>"0", "AddressLine1"=>nil, "AddressLine2"=>nil, "City"=>nil, "CountryName"=>nil, "SubDivision"=>nil, "State"=>nil, "ZipCode"=>nil}`

Comment: Ehh... I don’t see any correlation between names of the classes and keys in the hash.

Comment: @mudasobwa, I also observed the same. It doesn't seem possible.

Comment: @mudasobwa by the way, If I see the hash of most outer model, there seems a little possiblity, as inner models start with propertyname as:
`{"CreditCardDetail"=>{"CardholderName"=>"ZEESHAN MUSTAFA", "CVV"=>nil },"OtherComplexProp"=>{"xyz"=>"123", ...` Here `CreditCardDetails` is a complex property of the outer model. 

But still, it seems it will be come messy, as I'll have to change property names and stuff, in order to make use of reflection technique.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK there is no generic way to do this, perhaps partly because API responses **never** match your model structure 1/1. But it would be pretty easy to implement this. I would go with something like `MyModel.load_from_hash` factory method and then recursively call corresponding factory methods from children models. You could then extract this functionality to a Concern and there it is.